# BuddyPress slug prefix

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, buddypress

At the official BuddyPress website http://buddypress.org/ They are running a single WordPress installation with BP. However for some of the pages they have prefixed them with /community/ for example: http://buddypress.org/community/members/ not all slugs have been prefixed for example http://buddypress.org/register/

Any ideas on how this has been done and can be recreated as a client is requesting a similar feature for a project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

<strike>1. Update your permalink structure</strike>

```
/%postname%
```

EDIT: permalink structure applies to posts not pages.

<strike>2. Create a page with a slug **community**, create a sub-page with a slug **members**.</strike>

EDIT2:

Huh, I thought BP was a some sort of social network built on top of WP, but OK, I see my mistakes now :] So I downloaded the thing and had some moments with it. It seems that those url structures that you were talking about (**community/members**) are working out of the box. Specifically, 
`bp-core/bp-core-catch-uri.php` is where most of the fun is happening. The URI is analyzed and broken into pieces and goes through all sorts of filtering. The main point is that ***first part of URI that goes after domain is skipped if it doesn't mean anything*** (there is no such component probably), so you could create URIs like

```
mysite.com/blah-blah-blah/activity/groups
```

and it would have the same effect as

```
mysite.com/activity/groups
```

I've tested it and it seems to work. Although I strongly recommend to dig into the source code and understand all of the URI filtering details before doing anything serious. Hope it helps.

Comment: Pretty nasty way of doing it!

Comment: But I don't want to alter the permalink structure as I have it setup as /news/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Oh gosh, I messed things up. It seems that you don't have to update permalinks since they are applied to posts only? (fix me if I'm wrong) . So, if that's the case, you don't need to alter permalink structure. Only create page and a sub-page with specifed slugs.

Comment: Doing that just gives me empty pages. How do I link the original buddypress pages to these new ones?

Comment: Newly created pages are empty, yes. You need add content to them. Giving example of /community/members I wanted to show you how create these kind of url structures on your site. If you need to link newly created pages to buddypress you need to do some redirection. Possibly, by a plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Comment: Redirection is not what I'm after. I'm looking to rewrite the urls so all links auto use them like on the bp site.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to achieve? If get this right, you want to create url structures in form of /parent/child on your site and enable your code to display links to those pages in some slug-independent way?

Comment: No. I just want to add prefixes to the buddypress urls of my choosing like they have buddypress.org